# How to display a List of object in Kendo Grid in jquery?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am working on a project in which I need to display `List` of `objects` in `Kendo Grid`.
below is the code for data binding.

```js
  $("#GridProperty").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: $_BindPropertyData,
                            data: { "LegalEntityId": LegalEntityId, "DatasetId": DatasetId },
                            async: true,
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                GeoId: { type: "int" },
                                GeoDescription: { type: "string" },
                                GeoAbbreviation: { type: "string" },
                                //ComponentDesc: { type: "string", from: "CompModelList.ComponentDesc" },
                                Id: { type: "int" },
                                Amount1: { type: "decimal", from: "CompModelList.SaDataModel.Amount1" },
                                Amount2: { type: "decimal"}
                                //lstcompModel: {type: ""}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },

                noRecords: {
                    template: "<p style='margin-top:5px;'>There are currently no items available<p>"
                },
                height: 525,
                reorderable: true,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                resizable: true,
                columnMenu: true,
                selectable: "row",
                dataBound: function () {

                },
                columns: Columns

            });
```

**Description :**

I am returning list of objects as `json` from my `Action` . but i am not able to bind the list of objects in `kendo grid`.

I am breaking my head for last four days. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Can you post the json being returned by the action (to analyse structure of the data) 2) What exactly are you expecting the above code to achieve (simply display the data being returned or display a list returned in a single column) 3) Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I have attached the images as link.
[Datascreen](https://ibb.co/hEoiiF)
[List of Objects from action](https://ibb.co/hTSLVv)
[List of Objects from action](https://ibb.co/dFN9OF)

Comment: @Sandman
in List Of objects,Here is the data i need to bind in kendo grid.
It is having a **componentModelList** and further it is having one more list named **SADataModel** which is having **Amount 1** and **Amount 2**.

Comment: [Complex objects](http://www.telerik.com/forums/model---complex-model-with-nested-objects-or-list-of-objects) seem to be an issue for many, and unfortunately not much in the way of a suggested workaround.. Have you looked into using [`schema.parse`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse)? It can be used to convert the incoming data into a suitable format. In your case this would involve building a "flattened" object sonsisting of componentMondelList/SADataModel etc

Comment: Please post JSON being returned (at least isolated scenario) and your columns collection.